# Applinks intents not working on android

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, applinks, deeplink

I have an Android app that should open links on the app which clicks from the web browser.

I have the following intent filters:

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />


            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.mysite.com" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.mysite.com" />
        </intent-filter>
```

And also i checked the my signed sha256 key, package name etc from the assetjson file which is in the mysite/.well-known/assetlinks.json. Everythings looks correct. But the app still not opening when i click the links from the website.

Comment: Try to <><data android:scheme="http" android:host="mysite.com" android:pathPattern=".*"/><data android:scheme="https" android:host="mysite.com" android:pathPattern=".*"/> (With pathPattern and without www.)

Comment: i tried this but still doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:host="mysite.com" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: i noticed that my code was working when clicks from the google etc. But how can i working it on the web site?

Comment: Explain with more details. I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: i want to handle all clicks event on the web page. Not for just google etc.
For example when i am in the web page and then click a link i can redirect the my app. How can i achieve it. Applinks doest work in this case.

Comment: It doesn't makes sense. Whenever a link to mysite.com is triggered, you app will be launched, that's all.

Comment: What if i manuelly write to my site name on the address bar? In this case applinks doesnt works

Comment: This is the expected behaviour for all major browsers and you wont be able to change it. If user is writing the url in the browser, it means he/she wants to use the browser.

Comment: Thanks. But in the ios there is a bar top of the screen which provides to redirect to app. Is there way to achieve it in android?

Comment: No, at least not that I'm aware of unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks you for your helps